# Brand new AC unit makes whooshing sound and air "chokes"

Tags: hvac, repair, air-conditioning, cooling, sounds

My brand new AC recently started making a whooshing noise. It sounds kind of like a sudden gust of wind, but it repeats every few seconds. Another way I can think of to describe it: imagine a PC cooler running relatively silent, but still being able to hear it. Now imagine it increasing its RPM noticeably for just around a second. Now imagine it doing this continuously.

It's a ComfortStar split type 12k BTU.

It also doesn't result in air being blown faster but, when you can hear it, if you stand in front of the indoor unit, the air stops coming out for like half a second. Like the unit "chokes".

Things I've noticed and done:

- If I lift the front panel by 2-3 cm or more the phenomenon stops! I thought something might be pushing on the filters, or that it's not closing properly, but I can't see any issues...
- Efficiency doesn't seem to be affected, it still cools very well, but the sound is annoying.
- It only seems to happen on the low or auto fan setting. For example at medium, high or turbo setting seems to result in a steady stream of air uninterrupted by whooshings.
- It doesn't always happen. Sometimes I run it for hours with no annoying sound, other times it starts a few minutes after turning on the AC. Sometimes it stops for a while.
- I tried recording the sound but my phone doesn't really allow you to notice it when it occurs.
- I'm using the AC Unit with the front panel/lid just a bit open, is it wrong or bad for the unit to use it like that? (see picture with a red circle)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this a window unit, or a split system?

Comment: What is meant by your statement that it"chokes when making the sound". What is the sound it is making.

Comment: What type , brand / model? What is a wooshing sound? The only thing I can think of would be a loose squirrel cage blower. But more info would be needed.

Comment: is it level, or sloped slightly down in back (outside)? You want the condensation to run away from the window...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Split System

Comment: @d.george I mean, when the whooshing sound appears (every 10-20 seconds sometimes more it's random) the AC kind of chokes and does not blow air out for that second.

Comment: @dandavis it is a split unit

Comment: @EdBeal added a lot more info to the post. please read it and let me know

Answer (score 1):

I would verify the screw that connects the blower to the blower motor is tight, I have seen where a loose fan (squirrel cage) slipping has caused this exact issue. I don’t have time to look it up right now but there is usually a maintenance over ride some times the plastic cutout that looks like a horizontal I on the right lower side. This may allow you to view the problem and I am not sure but may allow for the filter to be removed and will still turn the blower on.

Comment: thanks will try and let you know

Comment: Did you solve it? I have the same problem. I take the lid off and works ok.